# Fixed position element disappears off the screen

Tags: html, css, css-position, fixed

I'm developing a website for my portfolio. I wanted to keep the navigation bar to the left of the screen at all times with the content on the right being able to be scrolled through.
I have put in a test button but the button is nowhere to be seen on the page.
I have researched and implemented various solutions, but the button would never appear on screen. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. 
This is my CSS style sheet

```css
.WRAPPER {
 text-align:center;
 padding:20px;
}

div.transbox {

 background-color: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid black;
 opacity:0.6;
 filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

div.transbox p {

 font-weight: bold;
 color: #000000;
 font-size:60px;
 opacity:1;
}

.HOME {  
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

.HEADING {
 font-size:92px;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:black;
 left:0; right:0;
 top: 20%; bottom:0;
}

 
.TITLEBODY {
 font-size:22px;
 color:black;
}

 
.NAVBAR {
 float: left;
 width:30%;
 position:fixed;
}


.BODY {
 float: right;
 width: 70%;
}
```

and this is my HTML

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="styleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" size:100%>
</head>

<body>
<div class="WRAPPER">
  <div class="HOME">
    <div class="HEADING">
      <p>Alex Hodson
        <br>Portfolio
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="TITLEBODY">
    <div class="NAVBAR">
      <img src="back.png">
    </div>
    <div class="BODY">
      Text will go here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you in advance
Alex

Comment: you don't have `.WRAPPER` and `.TITLEBODY` closed and `body` opened, start with that.

Comment: Thank you, i have closed them now but still no change in the result. I will amend the snippet above

Comment: the HTML Structure is not well formed. there are unclosed DIVs
Apart from that .. where is the button you are missing ? there is no
button in the html at all. Are you dynamically inserting it using javascript ? Then please show us the javascript.

Comment: after `</head>` add `<body>`, you missing that.

Comment: The button in the html is simply an img, it is not linked to anything at the moment.

Comment: there is a closing but no opening body - tag

Comment: thanks, I have now added <body>

Comment: ok, you add a  position fixed to your button, but no position for his parent elements, try to do that.

Comment: I have add position relative to all the parent elements but the img is still not present, when i reduce the size of the screen however the img is present. I want the user to have to scroll down to see the button however

Comment: .NAVBAR floats left and is fixed at the same time ... it's out of the normal page flow with position : fixed anyway ... please remove the float. furthermore you don't have any arguments like top, bottom, left, right to tell the browser where to render the fixed content !

Comment: Thanks Andre R, The image is now on the screen but when I try to get it level with the "BODY" div, (past the window) the image again disappears. How can i get the image to appear when the user has to scroll down